# Expressing “$n$ is the $k$-th number to satisfy $P$” in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If we're in the domain of natural numbers and want a formula that expresses that $n$ is the $k$-th number to satisfy $P,$ how would we write this? For example, if we're trying to express the least number that satisfies P, we could do that through the formula $Pn ∧ ∀x(Px→n≤x).$ If we wanted to express the second least number that satisfies $P,$ again no issue. But how do I expand this to $k$-th number while still keeping the formula well formed in FOL?

The way I think this might be doable is through this formula, or something like it [image]
So to find the k-th number we first show all the numbers before it in the sequence, indicate that it isn't any of them, and then show that it's the next least number to satisfy P.

But it has ellipses, so is it really a formula of FOL?

Comment: So are you looking for a single formula that uses k as one of its variables? So basically a formula $\phi(k,m)$ that means that the k-th number to satisfy P is m?

Comment: Yeah, exactly so

Comment: Ok, then your attempted formula doesn’t work: that would be more of a meta-logical schema that defines a different formula for each different $k$, rather than a single formula that has $k$ as an actual variable

Comment: Is $k$ an internal number or an external number?

Comment: @NickDoe: Did you understand my answer?

Answer (score 3):

It is excellent that you are asking yourself about the ellipsis. If $k$ is a fixed natural number, then your formula works. It *is* an FOL formula for each $k$, even if it is *different* for each $k$. I suspect that this is actually all you were looking for.

But your formula (and *DanielV*'s formula) both have length quadratic in $k$. Just for fun, we can actually do better:
  $∃x_{1..k}\ \Big( \ n = x_k ∧ \bigwedge_{i=1}^{k-1} ( x_i < x_{i+1} ) ∧ \bigwedge_{i=1}^k P(x_i)$
  $\quad\quad\quad{}∧ ∀y\ \big( \ P(y) ∧ y ≤ x_k ⇒ \bigvee_{i=1}^k ( y = x_i ) \ \big) \ \Big)$.

However, there is a highly nontrivial fact that if your base theory include [PA<sup>−</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations) (or even just Robinson's [Q](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic)), then we can actually have a **single** formula where $k$ is a parameter, instead of one formula for each $k$! Basically it is possible to encode any finite sequence as a single natural, such that there are definable functions $l,e$ over PA<sup>−</sup> where $l(c)$ is the length of the sequence coded by $c$ and $e(c,i)$ is the $(i{+}1)$-th term in the sequence coded by $c$ (for each $i<l(c)$). There are also definable functions over PA<sup>−</sup> for manipulation of sequences (e.g. constructing a singleton or obtaining the concatenation of two sequences). Using these, we can translate the above formula schema into a single formula where $k$ is a parameter, essentially by replacing the $k$ existential quantifiers in front by a single quantifier over finite sequences of length $k$:
  $∃x\ \Big( \ l(x) = k ∧ n = e(x,k) ∧ ∀i_{<k-1}\ ( \ e(x,i) < e(x,i+1) \ ) ∧ ∀i_{<k}\ ( \ P(e(x,i)) \ )$
  $\quad\quad\quad{}∧ ∀y\ \big( \ P(y) ∧ y ≤ e(x,k) ⇒ ∀i_{<k} ( y = e(x,i) ) \ \big) \ \Big)$.

By the way, *Bram28*'s approach is not incorrect, and is a reasonable 'intermediate' approach, but to justify that approach we must show that the extension (with the extra predicate-symbol and the added axiom) is *conservative* (i.e. every theorem that it proves can be proven by the original). That fact is essentially due to what I have explained above.

For reference take a look at Rautenberg's "[A Concise Introduction to Logic](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-concise-introduction-to-mathematical-logic)", specifically "definitorial expansion" for when we can extend a theory conservatively (including the use of $l,e$ above) as well as "Godel number" for the sequence coding.

Answer (score 2):

Where $P(x,y)$ means that the $x$-th number that has property $P$ is $y$, maybe you could introduce an axiom that recursively defines this:

$\forall x \forall y P(x,y) \leftrightarrow (P(y) \land \\ ((x = 1 \land \forall z (z < y \to \neg P(z))) \\ \lor (1<x \land \exists v \exists w (s(v) = x \land P(v,w) \land \forall z (w < z \land z < y \to \neg P(z))))))$

Here, $s(x)$ is a function that returns the successor of $x$, for which you can use the Peano axioms.

With this as a background axiom, you can just use $P(k,m)$ wherever needed.

Also, while user21820 is correct in pointing out that adding this as an axiom would not be obviously conservative, and that we can actually use a formula that does not introduce any new predicates using Godel’s encoding scheme, I do believe that the above method is a lot more practical. For example, if $Prime(x)$ is a formula that expresses that $x$ is s prime number (this is quite straightforward using the language of arithmetic), then you can use the above scheme to represent $Prime(x,y)$, where the $x$-th prime number is $y$, and you can actually prove something like $Prime(3,5)$ without too much trouble.

Comment: To clarify, we only need the axioms of Peano arithmetic?

Comment: Or does the entire equivalence have to be introduced as a new axiom?

Comment: @NickDoe The axiom I suggest would need to be added.  Also, you need to have an axiom defining $x<y$, such as: $\forall x \forall y \exists z \ x + s(z) = y$

Comment: I see, thank you.

Comment: @NickDoe: I didn't downvote this answer as it is not incorrect, but it's important to note that to justify adding a new predicate-symbol plus a new axiom like this we need something highly non-trivial. Please see my answer for more details.

Comment: Wait wait, I didn't say that your added axiom is not conservative! I said that it *is conservative* and the highly non-trivial reason is that sequence coding allows us to do what I did in my answer, and hence *conservatively extend* the theory in the manner you want. And indeed, doing so makes it of practical use, which is why I called it "reasonable". =)

Comment: Hmm let's just say that it takes some work to get from what I wrote in my post to a full justification for conservativity of adding recursive definitions like in your post. I'm not really in the mood to wade through the details right now haha.. I added one word to your post to make it correct; please let me know if you object! =)

Comment: @user21820 Oh!  Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by 'conservative' then ... I am not familiar with the concept, but figured it would be the idea that you don't want to add non-logical symbols to your language if not needed.... but I guess it's a different notion :)  Ugh! Sometimes I really wish I could take a course in advanced logic with a good and knowledgeable instructor!

Comment: @Bram28: Yes a conservative extension $T'$ of an FOL theory $T$ has more symbols and more axioms but every theorem of $T'$ that is in the language of $T$ can already be proven by $T$. $T'$ may prove additional theorems using the extra stuff, but it is as if the extra symbols and axioms are unnecessary for proving sentences in the original language. If you have any logic questions, you can ask me in [the logic chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic) as well! =)

Comment: @user21820 Oh, I see: I introduced a predicate that is not in the standard language of arithmetic (LA) ... and obvously not knowing anything about that predicate, Peano Arithmetic would not be able to prove anything with regard to that new predicate, but it is also not true that my expanded language and theory can suddenly prove more things with regard to standard arithmetic either (because we can get all those result using Godel's sequence-encoding). So a non-conservative extension is one that would add axioms that cannot be proven in PA but still be expressed in LA, e.g. Godel sentences.

Comment: Correct! And to add a bit, you know that your extension is *sound* for $ℕ$ because you can see from your meta-system (needs a tiny bit of set theory) that you can interpret your new theory as about $ℕ$ (with an interpretation of your new predicate-symbol $P$) in such a way that your added axiom is true. That tells you that you aren't doing anything wrong. On the other hand, to know that you aren't doing anything '*extra*', you need all the machinery of Godel coding and representability. And why should we care? Well, if anything sound goes, we might as well add a whole set theory on top. =)

Comment: @user21820 Ah, cool! Learned something again :) Thanks 21820!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> "But it has ellipses, so is it really a formula of FOL?"

Yes it still is.  For 1 given value of k there is 1 FOL expression in which k is not a free variable.  Technically, using $=$ makes it not FOL but that is a common thing to ignore.  If you are wanting to maintain k as a free variable, then you might need something as strong as this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374169/how-can-i-prove-that-primitive-recursion-preserves-representability-in-peano-a

---

Here is an alternative derivation of a formula.  It's pretty well known how to say $\exists ! j . P(j)$ "there is one value such that P holds:"

$$\exists s . P(s) \land \forall t. P(t) \to s=t$$

That can be continued for $\exists_2 j . P(j)$ "there are two values such that P holds:"

$$\exists s_1, s_2 . s_1 \ne s_2 \land P(s_1) \land P(s_2) \land \forall t. P(t) \to (s_1=t \lor s_2 = t)$$

That can be continued for $\exists_k j . P(j)$ "there are k values such that P holds:"

$$\exists s_1 \dots s_k . \underbrace{s_1 \ne s_2 \land \dots \land s_{k-1} \ne s_{k}}_{O(k^2) \text { distinctions }} \land \underbrace{P(s_1) \land \dots \land P(s_k)}_{O(k) \text{ conjunctions}} \land \forall t. P(t) \to (\underbrace{s_1=t \lor \dots \lor s_k = t}_{O(k) \text{ disjunctions}})$$

So to say "n is the k'th value such that P holds:"

$$P(n) \land \exists_k  j . j \le n \land P(j)$$

This has the problem of being $O(k^2)$ sized expression and that $k$ is not a free variable.  But $\le$ can mean anything you want.